# "Мебель красного дерева", "бутыль тёмного стекла" — почему исчез предлог "из"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

*В посл. четв. XVIII в. все большее место начинает занимать **мебель красного дерева** с хорошо видной текстурой древесины...*
[**Л. В. Беловинский. Энциклопедический словарь российской жизни и истории**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=4W5sUATx57MC&pg=PA433&lpg=PA433&dq=%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=7SLI0lnSx_&sig=hNzrSFGe15sztJmzFhnr4zNHZOA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJpfKIkPTYAhWFh7QKHayYDBo4FBDoAQgwMAI#v=onepage&q=%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0&f=false)

*Но ни весело гудящее пламя, ни стоящая на столе внушительная **бутыль тёмного стекла** не могли развеять мрачное настроение двух мужчин, расположившихся по обе стороны от очага.*
[**А. К. Дойл. Блюмендайкский каньон**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=6CE7BAAAQBAJ&pg=PT409&lpg=PT409&dq=%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BB%D1%8C%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=nWhnXxi7mU&sig=Jh63KhCUK4eBlJ6WNJDS9nsFyyw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJlIbghPTYAhUMaVAKHe_oDgA4FBDoAQg1MAI#v=onepage&q=%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BB%D1%8C%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0&f=false)

*Мебель* (из чего?) ***из*** красного дерева; *бутыль* (из чего?) ***из*** тёмного стекла — почему эти выражения часто употребляются без предлога "из"?
Или так неправильно говорить?

Answer (score 3):

**1) Мебель красного дерева** – родительный беспредложный падеж с общим определительным значением.

Примеры беспредложного Р. п.

1.1. **Материал:** рубашка голландского полотна, шапка золота литого. Мебель карельской березы. Портфель красной кожи.
*Синий, жесткого шелка кафтан расшит золотыми мордами и цветами* (А. Н. Толстой).

В этой конструкции не просто указывается материал, но он определяет важную характеристику предмета, относит предмет к определенному классу, задевает качество, выделяет  его из других предметов. Однако справедливо было указано, что эта форма носит **признаки архаичности и заменяется предложной формой**.

Источник: http://rus-yaz.niv.ru/doc/punctuation-rosental/articles/roditelnyj-padezh.htm

1.2. **Внешние признаки**: платье ослепительной белизны, лошадь серой масти, костюм черного цвета,  человек высокого роста.
В этом значении Р. п. используется часто, в отличие от материала.

**2) Мебель из красного дерева** – указание материала (из чего сделана мебель).

Мостовая из (мелких) булыжников, печь из (голубой) глины.

Answer (score 2):

Да можно с "из"! Да понятно ж и без!

Недаром роман ***исторический*** (мой любимый-прелюбимый и любимому посвящённый)! Прозрачный намёк на архаику!

[***В склянке тёмного стекла***](http://frolova.golos.de/ru/texte/V_sklyanke_temnogo_stekla.html)

*Булат Окуджава*

**Я ПИШУ ИСТОРИЧЕСКИЙ РОМАН**

*В. Аксёнову*

> В склянке тёмного стекла
>
> из-под импортного пива
>
> роза красная цвела
>
> гордо и неторопливо.
>
> Исторический роман
>
> сочинял я понемногу,
>
> пробиваясь как в туман
>
> от пролога к эпилогу.

---

> Каждый пишет, как он слышит.
>
> Каждый слышит, как он дышит.
>
> Как он дышит,так и пишет,
>
> не стараясь угодить:
>
> Так природа захотела.
>
> Почему?
>
> Не наше дело.
>
> Для чего?
>
> Не нам судить.

---

> Были дали голубы,
>
> было вымысла в избытке,
>
> и из собственной судьбы
>
> я выдергивал по нитке.
>
> В путь героев снаряжал,
>
> наводил о прошлом справки
>
> и поручиком в отставке
>
> сам себя воображал.

---

> Каждый пишет, как он слышит.
>
> Каждый слышит, как он дышит.
>
> Как он дышит, так и пишет,
>
> не стараясь угодить...
>
> Так природа захотела.
>
> Почему?
>
> Не наше дело.
>
> Для чего?
>
> Не нам судить.

---

> Вымысел - не есть обман.
>
> Замысел - еще не точка.
>
> Дайте дописать роман
>
> до последнего листочка.
>
> И пока ещё жива
>
> роза красная в бутылке,
>
> дайте выкрикнуть слова,
>
> что давно лежат в копилке:

---

> каждый пишет, как он слышит.
>
> Каждый слышит, как он дышит.
>
> Как он дышит, так и пишет,
>
> не стараясь угодить...
>
> Так природа захотела.
>
> Почему?
>
> Не наше дело.
>
> Для чего?
>
> Не нам судить.

---

*1975*

---

---

Да, ещё я приметила, что без "из" возможно только при наличии определения, стоящего перед определяемым словом!

Comment: Да-да, конечно, определение обязательно, это необходимо. Но ведь мы не говорим, например, печь (из) голубой глины или мостовая (из) мелких булыжников.

Comment: Мы легко можем сказать *печь голубой глины*, а вот с мостовой как-то не складывается...

Comment: Догадка, что там с мостовой... Мешает множественное число.

Comment: Возможно, дело не просто в определении, а в **цвете**, который сам по себе примыкает к существительным без предлогов: мы топали, отбрасывая "из"ы, по серого асфальта мостовой :) Ну и примелькаться должно конкретное сочетание. Мебель красного (цвета, из красного же) дерева - цвет материала переносится на объект. "Мебель морёного дуба" вроде как не говорили - сама мебель не "морёная".

Comment: Ну да, я ж и говорю: ***мы имеем дело с архаичной конструкцией***, лишь в немногих случаях принятых современным р. яз.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и отдельно — за Окуджаву.